# What is the noun for someone who receives a referral?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

When a referrer (noun) gives a referral (noun) to another person, what is the term (noun) used for the recipient of the referral? "The referred" may work, but am I missing another term? "Referred" indicates past-tense, but I intend to use the term in future and present tense as well.

Comment: This is just "[referee](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/referee)".

Answer (score 19):

Neither *referent* nor  *referee* seems quite suitable to denote the person who receives a referral.  Meanings of some relevant words include:
• *[referent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/referent)*: “That which is referenced”
• *[referee](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/referee#Noun)*: “A person who writes a letter of reference or provides a reference by phone call for someone”
• *[referrer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/referrer#Noun)*: “A person who refers another”
• *[referral](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/referral)*: “The act or process of transferring someone or something to another, of sending by reference, or referring” (or commonly, the documents for the transfer)

In a common scenario, Doctor A (the referrer or referee) writes a letter to specialist Doctor B (the referral recipient) about patient C (the referred) who needs special treatment.  From the Doctors' points of view, B is not a referent, referee, referrer, or referral, but can be called (accurately) a *referral recipient* or could be called (inaccurately?) a *referred doctor*.  The doctors are likely to call the patient a *referral* but if pedantic might say *referred patient*.  The doctors could also refer to the patient as *the referred*.  The patient might call B a *referral* or a *referred doctor*, but is more likely to say something like “I was referred to Doctor B”.  All of them call the letter of referral a *referral*.

In a similar but commercial scenario, the referral recipient (the party to whom the referred is referred) might be called an endorsed party, but could probably be called just *the endorsed* without confusion.

Answer (score 4):

referee:a person to whom reference is made, esp for an opinion, information, or a decision                                                                                                http://www.thefreedictionary.com/referee

Answer (score 1):

You could consider *[referent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/referent)* for whoever got the referral - as opposed to the referrer, who gave the referral.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/referent) supports this definition. I've often seen the word used in online marketing, but I'm not sure how well-known it is outside that context.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to try to use a noun formed from the verb *refer* here.

The fact that *referral* is one such — in this very special idiomatic sense of *refer* — is no guarantee either that there are any more forms like it to use (in that special idiomatic sense), nor that trying to use one is a good idea, even if they *do* exist.

For one thing, precisely what does *referral* mean? I have heard *referral* used to refer to:

- a letter of reference, written by X, for (= about) Y, to be sent to Z
- a note, written by X, requesting Z's attention to some request of Y's
- an address or URL, provided by X to Y, for the purpose of finding out about/contacting Z
- various other forms of information transfer

So if A gives B a referral, what exactly is changing hands or minds here?

Comment: In business when we give a customer a reference to do business with another business, it's considered a "referral". In the transaction of a referral in this manner, I assumed there would be an oft-used noun attached to the recipient. @Mark above mentions "referee", which could also work; however, that term is more often used as a sports judge and could lend to confusion. I may have to settle on "referee" if there are no other terms, however.