# What are the two parties of referencing called?

Tags: single-word-requests

If document A references document B, is there a term to describe A’s and B’s role?
Maybe we could call B the *referent?* How about A?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. If you can, please [edit] your question to add some context where you want to use these words and what you found so far. See http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/81653/42179

Answer (score 1):

Using terminology from

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-reference#Structure_of_a_cross_reference

I'd say :

A: **referencing document** (which contains references or cross-references)
B: **referenced content** (or item, section, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You're already mostly there with the wording of your question.

Document A is, simply, "the document". Document B is "the reference", or source.